# Asp.Net Core WebAPI [dotnet publish --self-contained -r linux-64] is it really self-contained after putting into Docker container

Tags: linux, docker, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I didn't notice any difference after these 2 runs of publish if compare **linux-self-contained** and **linux-dotnet** folders.

```
dotnet publish WebApi.csproj -c Release -o linux-self-contained --self-contained -r linux-x64
dotnet publish WebApi.csproj -c Release -o linux-dotnet -r linux-x64
```

Is it possible to achieve publishing mode for which **dotnet** ( Linux executable ) and any other prerequisites will go into single directory instead of /usr/bin
and it will work in Docker container ?

```
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyProject.WebApi.dll"]
```

Currently if browse contents of docker container

```
root@6e813cdc578d:/# find . -name dotnet
./usr/share/dotnet
./usr/share/dotnet/dotnet
./usr/bin/dotnet
```

The concept of single directory seems to work quite well for --self-contained .Net Core Console App with

```
ENTRYPOINT ["./MyLittleConsoleProgram"]
```

I don't see any **dotnet** occurrences in generated Docker image.

Basically, all this exercise was for achieving
[How to run dotnet core app with Selenium in Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55206172/how-to-run-dotnet-core-app-with-selenium-in-docker)

( **Second** answer which indeed works for console applications )

Since then it turned out that using selenium in a separate container is a better approach, which requires just one line code change in WebAPI.

Comment: The 2 ways of publishing are the same because the default value for `self-contained` is true

Answer (score 0):

The two commands are equivalent. When you use the `-r` switch in `dotnet publish WebApi.csproj -c Release -o linux-dotnet -r linux-x64`, it implicitly enables `--self-contained`. In .NET 6, this command will generate a warning telling you that you should explicitly provide either `--self-contained` or `--no-self-contained`. So if you want to provide the RID and do not want a self-contained deployment, you should include `--no-self-contained`.